# Installing old version of python packages

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-packaging

I done a project 4-5 years before, currently i needed that project now, there i used specific python packages, for example, matplotlib==1.5.1 and scipy==0.19.0 is needed and more.

To run that project now, I created a virtual env. with python version 3.5, but when installing those packages, I got `Error:could not find a version that satisfies a requirement` for all the python packages

I tried many solutions, but all ended in the same error

How to install those specific version, now? and, what are the possible ways to install those packages?

thanks

Comment: More details are probably needed, because this should work and we can not guess what went wrong. -- What have you tried exactly? What commands? What operating system?

Comment: @sinoroc, i tried, pip3 install matplotlib==1.5.1 in ubuntu system by creating the virtual envrionment with python version 3.6, for this, I got the error - couldnt find a version that satisfies a requirement

Comment: I recommend you try `path/to/venv/python -m pip install matplotlib==1.5.1` https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ -- Also you probably should try with Python 3.5 as it seems that is what this version of matplotlib is compatible with.

Answer (score -1):

**I Don't Know It will work or not but you can try this method too**

first create a requirements.txt file

then add you module with version like matplotlib==1.5.1 one by one

then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: If it doesn't work with normal pip install, I don't see why this would work.

Comment: @cycno, I tried this, same error, for the version 1.5.1, Error:could not find a version that satisfies a requirement, do you know any other way to install...